# how to create desktop shortcuts

Tags: shortcuts

how to create desktop short cuts as the different user logins?

Comment: Please create separate questions instead of asking multiple questions in one question. As for your first question of creating desktop shortcuts, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44678/how-to-add-a-shortcut-on-desktop?rq=1) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop).

Answer (score 0):

Create a shell script with the following code

```
dm-tool switch-to-user USERNAME
```

and save it as `/home/yourname/bin/login_script.sh`. Make sure it is executable

Now, add the script as a shortcut on desktop by creating a `~/Desktop/login.desktop` file with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Version=1.0  
Exec=/home/yourname/bin/login_script.sh  
Name=Switch User  
GenericName=Switch user
Comment=Login as different user
Encoding=UTF-8  
Terminal=true  
Type=Application  
Categories=Application;
```