How to add custom shortcut to a third party application in ubuntu 22.04
So I use Ctrl+Alt+T for opening my default Ubuntu terminal. Since I downloaded a new terminal, I wanted to make it my default. So I thought of replacing the shortcut key of the Ubuntu terminal with the new one. So I went to the custom key in settings:

and added the same key and also disabled it from the default terminal, but it still didn't work. Any idea how to sort it out?

Why not use the same command? I can write an answer to that if you want.

otherwise this will probably do https://askubuntu.com/questions/44678/how-to-add-a-shortcut-on-desktop

Can you add the screenshot of how you added the Custom Shortcut??

@amar I am using the same command but it isn't working for third party application. That's  my question!

Settings -> Keyboard -> View and Customize Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts  -> Add shortcut: and from there I added name as term, command as: ctrl + alt + T, and shortcut as same, @ajay

@Akash edit your question and add what you did that does not work.

You should give the executable path of your new terminal in the command section. Open up your terminal and run which term (I think that's the package name of your new terminal). You will get something like /usr/bin/term. Copy this output and paste it on the command section.

It should work. If it does not work, then your command may be wrong. You are not giving any information that is useful for us to sort out where you might have gone wrong, so try again.

Thank you folks for guiding me with the problem, I'll re frame the question with all the details.

@Akash Ah, sorry, I did not correctly understood your last comment to me and thought you were still talking about a shortcut. Here comes your answer.

How to create a Custom Keyboard Shortcut replacing CTRL+ALT+T

First you find the shortcut and disable it, Setting, keyboard, View and Customize Shortcuts,there you can simply write CTRL in search. It will show that in Launchers there is a Launch Terminal with CTRL+ALT+T, click on it and a choice of changing the command or disabling the command will show.

Second is your code test it. When I started with Linux I was looking for a standard way to customize shortcuts.


There was a mention in one of the answers here (unfortunately I can not find it to credit the person with the info, if you find the question let me know) that you can put any bash code in custom shortcuts if you put it in this format.
This is in one of my keys sh -c 'date "+%d %m %Y" | /usr/bin/xclip -r -sel c' and another sh -c 'gnome-extensions disable soft-brightness-plus@joelkitching.com ; gnome-extensions enable soft-brightness-plus@joelkitching.com'.
So as you see the code is sh -c 'yourcommand'. So simply get your exact terminal name and try it in this code, use the lower and upper keys exactly as the name, otherwise it will not work and test it.

Third go to Custom Shortcuts, and you can use the custom keys as instructed, and put your code in there.

